# Undefined local variable or method 'id' for #<moviesController:0xb3314d64> on Rotten Potatoes

Tags: ruby

I've been working on an Edx problem Homeowrk 2 for about 2 hours. I'm officially stuck. How do you make something. This problem has to do with

What I have to do is link Movie Title to as sort, so that it would sort Movie in order.

```
-#  This file is app/views/movies/index.html.haml
%h1 All Movies

%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= link_to 'Movie Title', new_movie_path
      %th Rating
      %th Release Date
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

According to the homework, I'm supposed to edit the index to so that it puts "all Movies" in order. I've looked up the sort method for ruby, and it is movie.order(). I don't know what to put in the parenthesis.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve movie ID from URI route
    @movie = Movie.find(id) # look up movie by unique ID
    # will render app/views/movies/show.<extension> by default
  end

  def index
    @movies = Movie.order(id)

  end

  def new
    # default: render 'new' template
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  def edit
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
    @movie.update_attributes!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully updated."
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end

  def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Movie '#{@movie.title}' deleted."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

end
```

So the root problems, I dont know how to edit the method index correctly to give my "Movie" directory order, and I dont know how to assign the header Movie Title to point to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view

```
 %th= link_to 'Movie Title', movies_path(sort_param: 'title')
```

and in the controller

```
  def index
    @movies = Movie.order(params[:sort_param])
  end
```

You could do the same for other headings like 'Rating', 'Release Date' etc as well.

Comment: That did not work I got a TypeError in MoviesController#index

It says you can't convert a symbol into integer.

Comment: Josh, what line does that correspond to?

Comment: the TypeError should be happening on a particular line - we need to know what code is on that line to help you

Comment: So I tried it a second time, and it works. THANK YOU! You are a life saver

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`ordering with Rails`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering). The variable `id` in your `index` function does not exist.

Comment: I have been looking at that ordering with rails link for a long while now. I can seem to implement it correctly. :(

Answer (score 0):

Make a scope in your model. This is the most suggested way. Your controller does not need to know how to retrieve your results. Just ask model what you need!

In the scope, design it how you want. Check [the doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for more info.

In your movie model file, put something like:

```
scope :ordered, order("id ASC")
```

Then in your controller index:

```
@movies = Movie.ordered
```

This will give your sorted movie collection